# How to generate fixed number of views from json API in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swiftui

So I am learning how to use SwiftUI with a json api.  I am currently generating views through a list and a ForEach Loop.  I am wondering how I can make it so that it only generates the first, say 10 elements in the posts array, instead of generating the entire list from the api. Basically I want to use RandomElement() to display 10 random posts from the entire array. I am just beginning here and learning so any help woul dbe appreicated.

Below is the code for my main view that is displaying the list

```
import SwiftUI



struct postList: View {
    //state variable of the posts
     @State var posts: [Post] = []
        var array = [Post]()


    var body: some View {

        List {

            ForEach(posts) { post in

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(post.title)
                    .font(.headline)

                Text(post.body)
                    .font(.callout)
            }
            .padding()

            }




        }
        .onAppear() {
            Api().getPosts { (posts) in
                self.posts = posts
            }
        }





    }
}

struct postList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        postList()
    }
}
```

Down here is the Data file I use to retrieve the json data

```
import SwiftUI

struct Post: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var body: String

}

class Api {

    func getPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> ()) {

        guard let url = URL(string: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts") else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            let posts = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(posts)
            }

        }
        .resume()

    }

}
```

Comment: EDIT:  I want to know how to simply get a section of the array to display in a List.  I want to start by being able to get a range of the array, then eventually be able to take 10 random elements from the array.

Comment: You should handle this through your model object - With SwiftUI your view is simply responsible for displaying the data from the model.  Create another object or struct to be your model rather than just using a simple array

Comment: Do you know of any good tutorials on where I could learn how to create this model?